# Scale out Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, database, autoscaling

I have a SQL Database in Azure. An S0 instance with 10 DTUs. This is enough 95% of the time.

However, when the App Service plan scales out (can go up to 20x in rare cases), I need 200/400 DTUs. Since this will not happen very often, so it would be a waste to always pay for these sizes. Is there a way to scale out the database when the app service scales out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to have a DB scale up when a Web App does, but there is a workaround. You can have the scale up action on the web app trigger a webhook, so you can have that call either Azure Automation or an Azure Function, which then talks to the ARM API to scale up or down your SQL DB.

See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-autoscale-to-webhook-email) to see how to trigger a webhook on scaling.

Comment: Thank you very much. Ill try to do so. Let's hope I wont accidentally scale out my database to something really really expensive ;)

Comment: Make sure you add checks to your script that prevents this

Comment: So i gave it a try. When upscaling the database, the application refuses to connect for a short while. System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Database 'xxx' on server 'xxx' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them th...

Comment: Correct, there will be a brief period where no new connections will be allowed, you need to build your application to handle this if you want to scale

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this? Like "SqlAzureExecutionStrategy"? Or should I really queue my queries until the db is reachable again?

Comment: At a basic level you could just build in retry logic, but yes  you could also look at sqlAzureExecutionStrategy